# Angular EventEmitter not working on some lazy loaded module

Tags: angular

I made `SharedModule`. Here is `SharedService` and it's imported in my `app.module.ts`.

I have many lazy-loaded modules and I am using `SharedService` to send data from `HeaderModule`
to another module's component.

But it's working only on some modules. What happened?

My problem is `SharedService`'s `EventEmitter` is working on dashboard module. so `dashboardModule`'s components are available to receive when `headerComponent` emit data through `sharedservice`.
but it's not working on the real-time module's component.

Here are my codes.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, MainComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRouting,
    HttpClientModule,
    UiModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [SharedService]
    }
  }
}
```

**shared.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
    public themeEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    changeTheme(event: any) {
        this.themeEmitter.emit(event);
    }
    onChangeTheme(subscribeFunc: any) {
        return this.themeEmitter.subscribe(subscribeFunc);
    }
}
```

**ui.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    ],
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        CommonModule,
        HeaderModule,
        LoginModule
    ],
    exports: [
        LoginModule,
        HeaderModule
    ],
    providers: [
        WebsocketService
    ]
})
export class UiModule { }
```

**dashboard.lazy.module.ts**

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        DashboardRouting,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            },
            isolate: true
        }),
    ],
    exports: [
        TranslateModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent,
        ...
    ],
    entryComponents: [
         ...
    ],
    providers: [
        DashboardService,
        BackendProvider
    ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

**realtime.lazy.module.ts**

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TreeModule,
        MonitoringRouting,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            },
            isolate: true
        })
    ],
    declarations: [
           ...
    ],
    providers: [
        RealtimeService
    ]
  })
  export class RealtimeModule { }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

One of imported module in `RealtimeModule`, that had `SharedService` in provider...

It was my mistake.

I don't think anyone's going to have the same basic problem as me, If you have same problem with me, `SharedModule(SharedService)` is must imported or define provider only in root module.

Comment: If it solve your problem, please mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Marco Pretty sure you'll have to wait a day before you can accept your own answer

Comment: @MikeS. Make sense.